# How to send either String or File through android socket?

Tags: java, android, string, sockets

I just realized that **DataInputStream** and **DataOutputStream** in writing reading socket
could be used to differentiate the input that was coming over.

Check this code:

**Server Side. (receiving string or file)**

```
Socket bSock = serverSocket.accept();
DataInputStream inp = new DataInputStream(bSock.getInputStream());

int iCode = inp.readInt();

        switch (iCode) {
                case Request.STATE_FILESHARING:
                    byte bp[] = new byte[iCode];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("s.pdf");
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    int bytesRead = inp.read(bp, 0, bp.length);
                    bos.write(bp, 0, bytesRead);
                    bos.close();
                    break;
                case Request.STATE_CONVERSATION:

                    requestFound = new Request(inp.readUTF());
                    sendToUI(requestFound);
                    break;
        }
```

**Client Side. (sending string or file)**

```
Socket socket = new Socket(myServerAddress, SocketServerPORT);

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

if (isThisFileMode()) {

            File myFile = new File(sLocationFile);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            out.writeInt(Request.STATE_FILESHARING);
            out.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            out.flush();

} else {

            out.writeInt(Request.STATE_CONVERSATION);
            out.write(obReq.toString().getBytes());
            out.flush();

}
```

But I ended up with Error. System crashed!
Anything that I forgot to add?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using `readUTF()` but not `writeUTF().` Nearly all the methods of DataInputStream and DataOutputStream are symmetrical: if you call `readXXX()` you must call `writeXXX()` at the other end.
2. You're making the usual mistake of assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. It is only contracted to transfer at least one byte. You must loop:

   ```
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
   {
       out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   ```
3. You need to close the socket at both server and client.